# When I run this , i am getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.. why is that?

Tags: python

```
def ceasarEncipher(pt,key):
    for i in range(0,len(pt)):
        ct=""
        currentChar=pt(i)
        numericChar=ord(currentChar)-ord('a')
        numericNewChar=(numericChar+key)% 26
        numbericNewChar=numericChar + ord('a')
        newChar=chr(numericNewChar)
        ct= ct + newChar
    return ct
```

this is what i am returning

```
ceasarEncipher('abcdef',1)
```

also  one more question i want the question to return 'bcdefg'but its returning '\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06' i m very confused please help – thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's because `pt` is a string and here:

```
currentChar=pt(i)
```

you try to call it as a function, passing in the argument `i`.  Remember that adding `(...)` after an object in Python calls that object.

What I think you really want to do is *index* `pt` with `i`.  For that, you need to use square brackets:

```
currentChar=pt[i]
```

---

However, there is almost *never* a reason to do:

```
for i in range(len(collection)):
    var = collection[i]
```

because you accomplish the same task a lot more efficiently with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def ceasarEncipher(pt,key):
    for idx,_ in enumerate(pt):
        ct=""
        numericChar=ord(idx)-ord('a')
        numericNewChar=(numericChar+key)% 26
        numbericNewChar=numericChar + ord('a')
        newChar=chr(numericNewChar)
        # This is the same as `ct = ct + newChar`
        ct += newChar
    return ct
```

In the above code, with each iteration of the for-loop, `idx` will be the current index.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
currentChar = pt(i) #It is considering this as a function call.
```

Should be

```
currentChar = pt[i] #access the index i of string pt
```

Demo:

```
>>> def ceasarEncipher(pt,key):
...     for i in range(0,len(pt)):
...         ct=""
...         currentChar=pt[i]
...         numericChar=ord(currentChar)-ord('a')
...         numericNewChar=(numericChar+key)% 26
...         numbericNewChar=numericChar + ord('a')
...         newChar=chr(numericNewChar)
...         ct= ct + newChar
...     return ct
... 
>>> ceasarEncipher('abcdef',1)
'\x06'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python uses square brackets to index strings`[]`:

```
currentChar = pt[i]
```

Comment: thanks so much , i think i was making a mistake with the square brackets also one more question i want the question to return
'bcdefg'but its returning '\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06' i m very confused please help